# How to install 4.5.2 nuget package in Mono project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, raspberry-pi, mono

I'm using Xamarin Studio 6.3 with Mono 5.4.1.6 for a Raspberry Pi 3 project. I need to install [Unosquare.Raspberry.IO](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unosquare.Raspberry.IO) C#/Mono API for interfacing with the Raspberry Pi, but when I am adding the package, I get this error:

> Could not install package 'Unosquare.Swan 0.16.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The package requires `.NET framework 4.5.2`. According to [Mono-Project](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/), Mono should be compatible/equivalent to `.NET 4.7`, but in Xamarin the latest target framework available is "Mono / .NET 4.5".

**So, is it possible to install/use this package?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible. I think I have to try rebuilding the package in the supported framework.